# Uploading video file to the URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to upload video file to the specified URL. When I press button video file should upload into the URL which I used. But no response is coming.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"3idiots" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *uploadurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://115.111.27.206:8081/vblo/upload.jsp"];

//NSData *postVideoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData *postVideoData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding         allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postVideoLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postVideoData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request12 = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[request12 setURL:uploadurl]; 
[request12 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request12 setValue:postVideoLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
[request12 setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request12 setHTTPBody:postVideoData];
NSURLConnection *theConnection12 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request12 delegate:self];

if( theConnection12 )
{
    webData12 = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    
}
else
{
    
}

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    
    [webData12 setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{   
    
    [webData12 appendData:data];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *loginStatus12 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData12 mutableBytes] length:[webData12 length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(loginStatus12);
     
    if(loginStatus12)
    {
        UIAlertView *statusAlert12 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:(NSString *)loginStatus12 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [statusAlert12 show];
    }
}
```

Comment: you really need to clean up this code, it is hard to read... also what is in the variable "string" looks like you have commented out the actual video data

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the request, add this line after you set the HTTPBody

```
NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request12 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur reply i used that, but not giving any response.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable sugession. may i know that whats wrong in my code.